# How to add Dokka to Android project without additional classpath in the dependencies section?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle-plugin, kotlin-dokka

How to add Dokka documentation engine support to Android project without adding to dependencies section additional classpath. I have compatibility issues...

Dokka documentation suggests following, but it's classpath breaks my build..

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:0.9.17"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'
```

Comment: what is the value of the variable `dokka_version`?

Comment: @Lino The value of the variable dokka_version = 0.9.17, updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only solution I could found:

## [EasyDokkaPlugin](https://github.com/Vorlonsoft/EasyDokkaPlugin)

Gradle script plugin to generate documentation by Dokka documentation engine in Javadoc format for Java, Kotlin, Android and non-Android projects. It's very easy, you don't need to add to `dependencies` section additional `classpath` or think about compatibility issues, you don't need additional repositories also.

### Usage

#### 1. Have a working Gradle build

It is up to you.

#### 2. Call the script

Add the following at the end of `build.gradle` of each sub-module that you wish to generate documentation:

```
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/Vorlonsoft/EasyDokkaPlugin/master/dokka.gradle'
```

#### 3. Generate documentation

You can now generate documentation by Dokka documentation engine in Javadoc format:

```
$ gradle dokkaJavadocsJar
```

#### 4. Get documentation

Get generated documentation from `${buildDir}` directory.